# If $\gcd(ab,c)=d$ and $c|ab$ then $c=d$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

For all positive integers $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$,
if $\gcd(ab, c) = d$ and $c | ab$, then $c = d$.

Need help proving this question, I know that $abx + cy = d$ for integers $x,y$
and that $c|ab$ can be $c=q\cdot ab$ but I'm not sure how to apply these facts or if they're even useful in this proof.

Any help to get me started would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$c|ab$ means that $ab=q\cdot c$, not the other way around!

Therefore, you have $ab=q\cdot c$ and $ab x + c y = d$ which you can rewrite into $$qcx + cy = d\\
c(qx+y) = d$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: yes I did mix that up. So from there since c(qx+y) = d if c =d then (qx+y) = 1?

Comment: @user3491814 You have to **prove** that $c=d$, you cannot assume that. Remember, you know that $d=\gcd(c, ab)$. This means that $d$ is a divisor of $c$...

Comment: There's a typo, 5xum: $q\cdot q$ should be $q\cdot c$ in the first line.

Comment: @CarlHeckman Thanks, fixed.

Comment: since qx+y is just an integer can we put cm = d for some integer m and then write c|d? and since we know d|c the only way that c|d is if they're equal. is that right?

Comment: @user3491814 There you go! All done. Another way of thinking would be to say that since $d|c$, you know that $d\leq c$, but since $d=c\cdot m$, you know that $d\geq c$, meaning that $c=d$.

Answer (score 0):

$ab$ is a red herring. When $y$ divides $x$, then $\gcd(x,y)=y$: the greatest common divisor is the largest divisor of both numbers; since $y$ is a divisor of $x$ and of course also a divisor of itself, it is eligible as common divisor. Then it's the greatest one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need $Bezout's \space Theorem$ to prove this. It follows directly from the definition of $gcd$. Clearly, the greatest divisor of $c$ is $c$ itself(find how?). So, $gcd(x,c)≤c$, for any $x$. Clearly equality holds if and only if $c$ is a divisor of $x$, too. Thus, we get the solution.